# Rails avoid repeating controllers (DRY)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I'm currently creating an application with 3 main resources : `:products`, `:contacts`, `:items`.
All of them can be accessed by visitor only on public RESTful methods such as `index` and `show`.

On the other hand, logged users, can access to any RESTFul actions. The problem is that, views for `index` and `show` are differents depending on visitors or users.

My problem is that actually I'm thinking of duplicating my controllers into a namespace `user`  related only to logged user. I know this is not a good idea since it's not DRY at all.

How should I do in order keep one single controller to achieve this? Or what's best practices around it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd advise devise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769402/devise-action-filter-for-actions-that-require-authentication. Could you elaborate on this: "The problem is that, views for index and show are differents depending on visitors or users." In which way should these actions be different?

Comment: u can make ur content conditional, means if user logged in then show this content and if not logged in then just show this content only... so its simple to bind ur content with conditions on the same view(page).

Answer (score 0):

If there are only minor difference between what a logged-in and non-logged-in user can see, just put some conditions in your view:

```
<% if logged_in %>
  <p>You are logged in!</p>
<% else %>
  <p>You're not logged in.</p>
<% end %>
```

If the differences are major you'll probably want to create two separate views (e.g. `/contacts/index.html.erb` and `/contacts/public_index.html.erb`), one for logged in users and one for non-logged, then place the logic in your controller:

```
def index

  ... your logic goes here

  if logged_in
    render 'index'
  else
    render 'public_index'
  end
end
```

Obviously your implementation will be different depending on how your login system is implemented, but that's the gist of it.

PS I second the recommendation above that you use Devise rather than trying to roll your own login system.